# JavaFX custom component does not appear

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying create a custom component in JavaFX. This component is the base of the dialogs that will be used in the application, basically it is a BorderPane with custom a title in top and a button in the bottom. Here is a picture of the component in SceneBuilder:

[image: dialogoComum.fxml in scene builder]

and here is the fxml declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?scenebuilder-stylesheet ../css/style.css?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <bottom>
    <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="-1.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
      <children>
        <Button fx:id="botaoConfirmar" alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT"    ellipsisString="" graphicTextGap="4.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#confirmar" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="165.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3a813f;" text="OK (F12)" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE" wrapText="false">
          <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" fx:id="x1" />
          </font>
          <stylesheets>
            <URL value="@../css/style.css" />
          </stylesheets>
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
        </Button>
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </bottom>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@../css/style.css" />
  </stylesheets>
  <top>
    <HBox alignment="TOP_LEFT" disable="true" fillHeight="true" focusTraversable="true" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="-1.0" spacing="0.0" style="-fx-background-color: #3a813f;&#10;-fx-background-position: 100;" visible="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
      <children>
        <Text fx:id="titulo" fill="WHITE" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="TITULO" textAlignment="CENTER" wrappingWidth="0.0" x="0.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
          <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
          </font>
          <HBox.margin>
            <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
          </HBox.margin>
        </Text>
      </children>
    </HBox>
  </top>
</fx:root>
```

As you could see, my intention is use this component as a base dialog and put the content of a specific dialog in center:

[image: dialogoMensagem.fxml in scene builder]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lutum.ui.controladores.*?>
<?import com.lutum.ui.controladores.DialogoComum?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?scenebuilder-classpath-element ../../../../../target/ui-0.1.0.jar?>

<DialogoComum maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <center>
    <VBox prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
      <children>
        <HBox maxWidth="400.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
          <children>
            <ImageView id="icone" fitHeight="64.0" fitWidth="64.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" HBox.hgrow="NEVER">
              <HBox.margin>
                <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
              </HBox.margin>
            </ImageView>
            <Text id="mensagem" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text">
              <HBox.margin>
                <Insets right="10.0" top="20.0" />
              </HBox.margin>
            </Text>
          </children>
        </HBox>
        <Accordion id="accordion" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
          <expandedPane>
            <TitledPane fx:id="x2" text="Detalhes">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="-1.0" minWidth="-1.0" prefHeight="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0">
                  <children>
                    <Text id="detalhes" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="26.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" />
                  </children>
                </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </TitledPane>
          </expandedPane>
          <panes>
            <fx:reference source="x2" />
          </panes>
          <VBox.margin>
            <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
          </VBox.margin>
        </Accordion>
      </children>
    </VBox>
  </center>
</DialogoComum>
```

As you can see the component can be used correctly in SceneBuilder, however, the same don't happen when I use it in the application, I can simply see a white screen:

[image: white screen]

Here is the code for the DialogoComum (for dialogoComum.fxml):

```
public class DialogoComum extends BorderPane implements IControladorDialogo {

    @FXML
    protected Text titulo;
    protected URL modelo;
    protected Stage stage;
    protected List<String> estilos = new ArrayList<String>();

    public DialogoComum() {
        /*needed by SceneBuilder*/
        this.modelo = getClass().getResource("/gui/dialogos/dialogoComum.fxml");
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(modelo);
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public DialogoComum (String nothing){
        //Just to not call the above constructor
    }

    @Override
    public final void init() {
        try {
            stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(carregarCena());
            stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setWidth(200);
            stage.setHeight(200);
            configurarElementos();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    protected final Scene carregarCena() throws IOException {
        SpringFXMLLoader.load(modelo.openStream(), this);
        Scene cena = new Scene(this);
        cena.getStylesheets().addAll(estilos);
        return cena;
    }

    protected void configurarElementos() {}

    @FXML
    public void confirmar(ActionEvent evento) {}

    @Override
    public void abrir() {
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    @Override
    public void fechar() {
        stage.close();
    }
}
```

and ControladorDialogoMensagem (for dialogoMensagem.fxml):

```
public class ControladorDialogoMensagem extends DialogoComum {

    @FXML
    private Text mensagem;
    @FXML
    private Text detalhes;
    @FXML
    private ImageView icone;
    @FXML
    private Accordion accordion;
    private URL iconeSucesso;
    private URL iconeAlerta;
    private URL iconeErro;

    public ControladorDialogoMensagem() {
        super(null);
    }

    .
    .
    .

    @FXML
    public void confirmar(ActionEvent e) {
        fechar();
    }
}
```

finally here is the application code

```
public class AppBase extends Application implements ApplicationContextAware {

    protected ControladorDialogoMensagem dialogoMensagem;
    protected ApplicationContext contexto;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext contexto = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/appContext.xml");
        dialogoMensagem=contexto.getBean(ControladorDialogoMensagem.class);
        dialogoMensagem.abrir();
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

What can I do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

in <fx:root> you can't use the <stylesheets> tag. Instead use an attribute on the fx:root element like this:

```
<fx:root stylesheets="@chatlist.css" type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```